# Trying ajax in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to use Ajax in RoR. 
Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Controller:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.js
    else
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

create.js.erb:

```
$('#post_title').value('');
$('#post_content').value('');
$('#my_posts').prepend('<%= j render @post %>');
```

index.html.erb:

```
<h1>New Post:</h1>

<%= simple_form_for @post, remote: :true do |f| %>
  <div class="my_form">
    <%= f.input :title    %>
    <%= f.input :content  %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Posts</h1>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Content</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id='my_posts'>
    <%= render @posts %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.
Please correct me or advise a good and simple tutorial.

UPD:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-03 03:07:37 +0300
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
  Rendering posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
  Rendered collection of posts/_post.html.erb [7 times] (1.5ms)
  Rendered posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (34.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 269ms (Views: 257.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)


Started POST "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-03 03:07:44 +0300
Processing by PostsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "post"=>{"title"=>"123", "content"=>"321"}, "commit"=>"Create Post"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" ("title", "content", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["title", "123"], ["content", "321"], ["created_at", 2016-10-03 00:07:44 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-10-03 00:07:44 UTC]]
   (143.9ms)  commit transaction
  Rendering posts/create.js.erb
  Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered posts/create.js.erb (2.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 155ms (Views: 4.0ms | ActiveRecord: 144.1ms)
```

Comment: You use `#` in your JS file, but those should be `$`

Comment: @Koen. Thank you, but it also doesn't work. :c

Comment: @DartNyan looks like everything fine, can u post yr server log for request

Comment: What's the point of the `if @post.save` condition if you just use `format.js` when it's either `true` or `false`

Comment: You can also try restarting your server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your code looks fine except for these lines which need to be removed
`$('#post_title').value('');`
`$('#post_content').value('');`

I recreated the project and it worked when I removed those lines of code. Not sure why you need them in the first place because when you hit the `create` action, the javascript first renders `@post` which will create the HTML code  for the newly created `post object / (@post)` using the `post partial`. And then finally that HTML code is prepended to the `#my_posts` element displaying the `title` and `content` of the new `post` so I'm not sure what those lines are supposed to accomplish. Hopefully that should solve the problem

Just in case, this is what my code looked like

**test_app/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @post = Post.new
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.js
      else
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
  end
end
```

**test_app/app/views/posts/index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @post, remote: :true do |f| %>
  <div class="my_form">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'text'    %>
    <%= f.label :contnet %>
    <%= f.text_field :content, class: 'text'  %>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<h1>Posts</h1>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Content</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id='my_posts'>
    <%= render @posts %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**test_app/app/views/posts/_post.html.erb**

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <%= post.title %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= post.content %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**test_app/app/views/posts/create.js.erb**

```
$("#my_posts").prepend('<%= j render @post %>')
$('.text').val('')
```

Comment: Man, I'm so grateful. This happened because of `$('#post_title').value('');
$('#post_content').value('');`

Comment: But I want to clear my inputs after creating a post. How can I do it?

Comment: They should be clear after you submit a post. When I recreated this app, my textfields were clear after a post submission. You can cross check with my code, I don't know if you have any other javascript file that could cause this but ideally the text inputs should be clear after a submit. I have never worked with `simple_form_for` but could you try using a `form_for` to see if there's any difference. Lets start debugging from there cos that's the first difference I can see right now. If that doesn't work, let me know

Comment: I've used your code, but it still works without clearing text fields after creating a post.

Comment: I see what you mean, I've edited the answer. I added a class`text` to both `textfields` in the `index` view and then cleared it in the `js` file. It should work fine now :)